# Pioneer spacecraft anomaly

Tags: new-horizons, pioneer

Has the possibility of the ["Pioneer Anomaly"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly) as caused by currently inadequate conceptual models of gravity been put to rest by explaining it as caused by on board thermal radiation ? What is the current status of plans, or a lack thereof, to compare thermal acceleration effects demonstrated by the New Horizons spacecraft with that of Pioneer ?

Comment: See http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/could-radiated-heat-propel-space-craft-in-outer-space/3594#3594 and http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15075/did-new-horizons-also-demonstrate-the-pioneer-anomaly  The Pioneer Anomaly has been fully explained by radiation pressure from onboard heat sources.

Comment: @Hobbes has also [already answered the rest of the question](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/15086/12102) *about New Horizons* as well in the second link in the comment above. So I think this question is 100% answered previously. If you just click the [new-horizons tag](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-horizons) you can see the question right below yours. It's a good question! It seems that since the "Pioneer Anomaly" can be explained by carefully modeling the *temperature AND emissivity* distributions on the spacecraft, there's no big science motivation to look again.